# MediaPlayer Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#, windows, media-player, virtual-machine, windows-server-2012

I made my own media player using System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer and it's working perfectly on Windows 7/Windows 8/Windows 8.1, but when I am using my media player on Windows Server 2012 I receive the error "Error: System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer.ExceptionEventArgs". What can I do to fix that ?

The server on which I want to run the media player it's not mine and I don't have unattended access to it so I created a virtual machine with Windows Server 2012 on it, but I received the same error. Also I have to mention that the application is using .NET Framework 4.5 which I can see that it's already installed on Windows Server 2012.

Please help me with these guys !

Comment: Sounds like you aren't logging the error very well. Did you call ToString on the type rather than getting the message?

Comment: @AlexBeisley, that's how I print the error : System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Error: " + e);

Comment: Yes, but apparently e.ToString() returns the default: System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer.ExceptionEventArgs, which means you need to try e.ErrorException, which gives you the exception, and then possibly .Message on that. Then you should get the actual issue.

Answer (score 2):

Add this feature; User Interface and Infrastructure > Desktop Experience.

After that try that.